# Using Scala Akka framework for blocking CLI calls

Tags: scala, akka, blocking

I'm relatively new to Akka & Scala, but I would like to use Akka as a generic framework to pull together information from various web tools, and cli commands.

I understand the general principal that in an Actor model, it is highly desirable not to have the actors block.  And in the case of the http requests, there are async http clients (such as Spray) that means that I can handle the requests asynchronously within the Actor framework.

However, I'm unsure what is the best approach when combining actors with existing blocking API calls such as the scala ProcessBuilder/ProcessIO libraries.  In terms of issuing these CLI commands I expect a relatively small amount of concurrency, e.g. perhaps executing a max of 10 concurrent CLI invocations on a 12 core machine.

Is it better to have a single actor managing these CLI commands, farming the actual work off to Futures that are created as needed?  Or would it be cleaner just to maintain a set of separate actors backed by a PinnedDispatcher?  Or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Akka documentation ( http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/general/actor-systems.html#Blocking_Needs_Careful_Management ):

"
***Blocking Needs Careful Management***

In some cases it is unavoidable to do blocking operations, i.e. to put a thread to sleep for an indeterminate time, waiting for an external event to occur. Examples are legacy RDBMS drivers or messaging APIs, and the underlying reason in typically that (network) I/O occurs under the covers. When facing this, you may be tempted to just wrap the blocking call inside a Future and work with that instead, but this strategy is too simple: you are quite likely to find bottle-necks or run out of memory or threads when the application runs under increased load.

The non-exhaustive list of adequate solutions to the “blocking problem” includes the following suggestions:

- Do the blocking call within an actor (or a set of actors managed by a router [Java, Scala]), making sure to configure a thread pool which is either dedicated for this purpose or sufficiently sized.
- Do the blocking call within a Future, ensuring an upper bound on the number of such calls at any point in time (submitting an unbounded number of tasks of this nature will exhaust your memory or thread limits).
- Do the blocking call within a Future, providing a thread pool with an upper limit on the number of threads which is appropriate for the hardware on which the application runs.
  Dedicate a single thread to manage a set of blocking resources (e.g. a NIO selector driving multiple channels) and dispatch events as they occur as actor messages.

The first possibility is especially well-suited for resources which are single-threaded in nature, like database handles which traditionally can only execute one outstanding query at a time and use internal synchronization to ensure this. A common pattern is to create a router for N actors, each of which wraps a single DB connection and handles queries as sent to the router. The number N must then be tuned for maximum throughput, which will vary depending on which DBMS is deployed on what hardware."